# Minimalist cocoa app does not appear in dock

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, sdl

As part of a broader project, I am implementing my own window management for a Cocoa app. I'm using the "objective c++" flag when compiling because much of the codebase is in c++.

I have put some stub code in my main.cpp to get a window to open but the window icon is not going in the applications dock and isn't raising itself to the front of the window stack.

I have this bit in my main.cpp :

main.cpp

```c
    TestAppDelegate* appDel = [TestAppDelegate alloc];
    [NSApp setDelegate:appDel];

    NSApplication* app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    app.delegate = appDel;
    [app run];

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
```

And my AppDelegate object looks like this

test.h

```c
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate> {

NSWindow * win;

}
@end
```

test.cpp

```c
#include "test.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NSRect rect;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    rect.size.width = 500;
    rect.size.height = 500;

    unsigned int style = (NSWindowStyleMaskTitled|NSWindowStyleMaskClosable|NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable);

    NSWindow* win = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:style backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:FALSE];

    NSButton* butan = [NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"SomeText" target:nil action:nil];
    butan.frame = NSMakeRect(20, 20, 100, 30);
    butan.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Things"];
    [win.contentView addSubview:butan];
    [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

It's a bunch of useless test code for now but the window opens up although it appears behind the Xcode editor. The button is responsive to clicks and the window is not frozen since I can move it around freely.

My problem is that the window doesn't seem "active". It's not in the dock, I can't "command+tab+ to reach it and when I click on it and give it focus the top-left buttons don't light up like the other applications.

What am I forgetting here ?

As a reference, I am looking at the source of [SDL](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/src/video/cocoa/SDL_cocoawindow.m), which my project mainly use except for this little experiment. If I start a graphical window with SDL, which uses Cocoa as its driver. I will see the window on the dock and it will be more "active" than my little window.

Comment: Is your app bundled (i.e. in a .app directory, etc.)? Or is a standalone executable? If it's bundled, show the Info.plist file. [Just as a clarification: on macOS, windows don't appear in the Dock (unless minimized), applications do.]

Comment: No my application is not bundled. If I inspect the output binary it says "Unix Executable". But it's interesting because if I run my application and windows with SDL (without creating NSWindow manually) I will get a dock icon and a more responsive window.

Also : If I minimize my NSWindow, I will get a minimized window in the dock, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your program is not a bundled app, you'll need to configure its "activation policy" to make it show up in the Dock and Command-Tab switcher:

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
```

You'll also want to activate it on launch:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

Comment: That did it, thanks ! Perfect answer.

If you don't mind me asking, where did you find this information ? Is this documented somewhere ? I'd love to learn more about the architecture of Cocoa applications but I have not managed to find a good resource for it. I found the official Apple documentation to be ... lacking.

Comment: I'm afraid that "where" is lost in the mists of time. I've been programming Macs for a *long* time. Also, I've generally relied on Apple's documentation rather than, say, third-party books. The quality of Apple's docs has declined. Some of the better docs are now in the "archive", not because they are wrong or incomplete, but because they are in an old style. For example, <https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13>.

Comment: I tried looking in the docs archive but there's a lot of stuff in there and I found it hard to find information unless you already know the keyword of what you're looking for. I'll definitely spend some more time in there though, looks interesting. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah. There's "Getting Started" and "Guides" in the left sidebar, which help some.